# Methods specific only to an instance? What are they called in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, singleton

I know there are "instance methods", "class methods" but what are these types of methods called, for eg:

```
s1 = "This is my STRING!"

def s1.m1
  downcase
end

p s1     # => "This is my STRING!"
p s1.m1   # => "this is my string!"
```

What type of method is the "m1" method called on the s1 "instance" of the "string" class? It's really weird because I didn't know this was possible at all if I try:

```
s2 = "This is ANOTHER string"
s2.m1 # => Won't work!
```

Which kind of makes sense, but not sure why defining methods like m1 on instances on a class are useful at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called singleton methods, and can be defined as follows:

```
class Person
  def favorite_meal
    "Big Mac"
  end
end

Fred, Joe = 2.times.map { Person.new }

def Fred.favorite_meal
  "Le Big Mac"
end

Joe.favorite_meal #=> Big Mac
Fred.favorite_meal #=> Le Big Mac
```

Other ways to define the same singleton method would be:

```
Fred.define_singleton_method :favorite_meal do "Le Big Mac" end
```

And:

```
class << Fred
  def favorite_meal
    "Le Big Mac"
  end
end
```

May the force be with you.

---

UPDATE: Answering the 2 questions from the comment.

Let me start by the 2nd one. It is up to you, whether you use a constant or a variable. It is perfectly OK to write `fred = Person.new`. But:

1. Objects with distinct properties often deserve proper names, which are properly capialized.
2. There is a useful gem I wrote, `y_support/name_magic`, that works by assigning to constants.

Install it by `gem install y_support`, and try:

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'

class Dog
  include NameMagic
  def speak; puts "Bow wow!" end
end

Spot, Rover = 2.times.map { Dog.new }
```

Now the `Dog` class knows its instances, and the instances know their names.

```
Dog.instances.map { |dog| dog.name } #=> :Spot, :Rover
Dog.instances.names # the simpler way to say the same
```

This is not useful in this particular example (and extremely useful elsewhere), but in any case, it gave me a habit of giving objects with personalities capitlized proper names.

As for the 1st question, `def Fred.foobar` is the most basic, one-off singleton method definition. If you want to define *several* singleton methods, or alias, or include a module in the singleton class, use `class << Fred`:

```
module Foo
  def bar; "Fretbar!" end
end

class << Fred
  include Foo
  alias le_favorite favorite_meal
end

Fred.bar #=> Fretbar!
Fred.le_favorite #=> "Le Big Mac"
```

The most advanced things are possible with `Fred.define_singleton_method` syntax, and with the 4th way, which I have not mentioned earlier:

```
local_var = 42

Fred.singleton_class.class_exec do
  define_method :baz do local_var + 1 end
end

Fred.baz #=> 43
```

This way uses closures, which retain binding to the variable `local_var`. Try it out

```
local_var = 32
Fred.baz #=> 33
```

So this is what's special about the syntax with closures, and it is often a godsend that magically solves nasty programming problems.

Comment: *+1* for such an detailed explanations... I like detail ones always.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What's the most common use people define them out of those 3 you outlined? I also noticed you used Capitalized letters for the variable names, maybe there's some convention that says to define variable names with capital letters in case you define any singleton methods for them?

Comment: @daremarkovic: Your interest makes me happy. I will answer by editing the post.

Answer (score 2):

They are called object `Singleton Methods`.

A `example` i can think of where you could use that:

You have a special logging class and you have to limit the logging to only one instance because you want your logging file to be clean and tidy.

Maybe not the best example, but if your interested in the use cases, look for use cases for the `Singleton Pattern` and you should find your answers there.

Answer (score 1):

They are called singleton method. Here is some way to check those:

```
s1 = "This is my STRING!"

def s1.m1
  downcase
end

klass= s1.singleton_class # => #<Class:#<String:0x902d4e8>>
klass.instance_methods(false) # => [:m1]
s1.method(:m1).owner # => #<Class:#<String:0x902d4e8>>
s1.singleton_methods # => [:m1]
```

> but not sure why defining methods like m1 on instances on a class are useful at all.

These singleton method(`m1`) can only be called only by `s1`,as you defined it inside the singleton class of `s1`. But not by any other instances of the `String` class. These are needed when you are having some behaviors that are unique to the object,irrespective of the fact that,if they are belonging to the same class or different class(s).

> s2.m1 # => Won't work!

Because you didn't define it inside the singleton class of `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

"(...)but not sure why defining methods like m1 on instances on a class are useful at all."

It makes this behaviour possible:

```
class Test
  def self.some_meth
  end
end
```

Test is just an instance of Class, and some_method is added to this specific instance.

```
p Test.singleton_methods #=> [:some_meth]
```